# Getting factory_girl to work in Rails3

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

For the life of me, I can't get `factory_girl` to work in Rails3. I created a brand new application. My Gemfile:

```
gem "rspec"
gem "rspec-rails"
gem "factory_girl_rails"
```

The generators in `application.rb` like so:

```
  config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => false, :fixture_replacement => :factory_girl
  end
```

Then, using the generator to create a new model:

```
> rails g model Addon name:string

  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20101223205918_create_addons.rb
  create    app/models/addon.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/addon_spec.rb
   error      factory_girl [not found]
```

What'd I miss? I did run `bundle install` of course... I tried looking around, but can't find any decent documentation on factory_girl and rails3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is https://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators.

> Rails 3 compatible generators for gems that don't have them yet...
>
> The Factory Girl generators have moved to [the factory_girl_rails gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails)...

Comment: Not needed with Rails 3.2 ... this is a bit out of date now

Answer (score 3):

This is the proper approach in Rails 3.2 as of today:

```
Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: true
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
end
```

Comment: Just tried this with test/unit and it didn't work. Is this RSpec-only syntax? I used: `g.test_framework :test_unit, fixture: true` and `g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl`

Answer (score 2):

Some users may be using `factory_girl`. Make sure that you are using `factory_girl_rails`.